# Angular @ViewChild() error: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1

Tags: angular, typescript, viewchild

When trying ViewChild I am getting the error. Error is "An argument for 'opts' was not provided."

Both @ViewChild is giving the error.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Ingredient } from 'src/app/shared/ingredient.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-shopping-edit',
  templateUrl: './shopping-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shopping-edit.component.css']
})
export class ShoppingEditComponent implements OnInit {

@ViewChild('nameInput') nameInputRef: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('amountInput') amountInputRef: ElementRef;
@Output() ingredientAdded = new EventEmitter<Ingredient>();
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onAddItem() {
    const ingName = this.nameInputRef.nativeElement.value;
    const ingAmount = this.amountInputRef.nativeElement.value;
    const newIngredient = new Ingredient(ingName, ingAmount);
    this.ingredientAdded.emit(newIngredient);
  }

}
```

> ts(11,2): error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.

Comment: What is in line 11 ?

Comment: @TonyNgo @ViewChild('nameInput') nameInputRef: ElementRef;

Answer (score 625, accepted):

In Angular 8 , ViewChild takes 2 parameters

```
 @ViewChild(ChildDirective, {static: false}) Component
```

Comment: can you please mark it as accepted?  From Angular docs: static - whether or not to resolve query results before change detection runs (i.e. return static results only). If this option is not provided, the compiler will fall back to its default behavior, which is to use query results to determine the timing of query resolution. If any query results are inside a nested view (e.g. *ngIf), the query will be resolved after change detection runs. Otherwise, it will be resolved before change detection runs.

Comment: You should add that to the answer if you want him to accept your answer as the best one

Comment: Note: to keep the behavior you had in Angular 7, you need to specify `{ static: true }`. `ng update` will help you do this automatically where needed. Or, if you've already upgraded your dependencies to Angular 8, this command will help migrate your code: `ng update @angular/core --from 7 --to 8 --migrate-only`

Comment: If the element needs to be available during ngOnInit, then static needs to be `true`, but if it can wait until after the init it can be `false`, which means it won't be available until ngAfterViewInit/ngAfterContentInit.

Comment: I got this error as well, but still need to know what happend if static: true? Thanks

Answer (score 114):

### Angular 8

In Angular 8, ViewChild has another param

```
@ViewChild('nameInput', {static: false}) component : Component
```

You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/28810) and [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/embrace-yourself-angular-8-is-coming-1bf187c8f0bf)

### Angular 9 & Angular 10

In `Angular 9` default value is `static: false`, so doesn't need to provide param unless you want to use `{static: true}`

Comment: In one of the articles you linked to, they show syntax like `@ContentChild('foo', {static: false}) foo !: ElementRef;`. I'm curious about the exclamation mark. Is that something new with Angular 8 too?

Comment: @KonradViltersten see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56950936/2279488

Answer (score 44):

In Angular 8 , `ViewChild` takes 2 parameters:

Try like this:

```
@ViewChild('nameInput', { static: false }) nameInputRef: ElementRef;
```

**Explanation:**

> { static: false }

If you set **static false**, the child component ALWAYS gets initialized after the view initialization in time for the `ngAfterViewInit/ngAfterContentInit` callback functions.

> { static: true}

If you set **static true**, the child component initialization will take place at the view initialization at `ngOnInit`

By default you can use `{ static: false }`. If you are creating a dynamic view and want to use the template reference variable, then you should use  `{ static: true}`

For more info, you can read this [article](https://www.thecodecampus.de/blog/angular-viewchild-static-property-in-ng8/)

> **[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tb4awr?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

In the demo, we will scroll to a div using template reference variable.

```
 @ViewChild("scrollDiv", { static: true }) scrollTo: ElementRef;
```

With `{ static: true }`, we can use `this.scrollTo.nativeElement` in `ngOnInit`, but with `{ static: false }`,  `this.scrollTo` will be `undefined` in `ngOnInit` , so we can access in only in `ngAfterViewInit`

Answer (score 9):

it is because view child require two argument try like this

> @ViewChild('nameInput', { static: false, }) nameInputRef: ElementRef;
>
> @ViewChild('amountInput', { static: false, }) amountInputRef:
>   ElementRef;

Answer (score 4):

In Angular 8, ViewChild always takes 2 param, and second params always has 
*static: true* or *static: false*

You can try like this:

```
@ViewChild('nameInput', {static: false}) component
```

Also,the `static: false` is going to be the default fallback behaviour in Angular 9.

What are static false/true:
So as a rule of thumb you can go for the following:

- `{ static: true }` needs to be set when you want to access the
  ViewChild in ngOnInit.

  `{ static: false }` can only be accessed in ngAfterViewInit. This is
  also what you want to go for when you have a structural directive
  (i.e. *ngIf) on your element in your template.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in angular 8.0:

```
@ViewChild('result',{static: false}) resultElement: ElementRef;
```

Comment: this question is one year old, but you has reason, in Angular 8.0 was neccesary {static:true/false}. In Angular 9 and 10 this argument is optional

Answer (score 1):

Regex for replacing all via IDEA (tested with Webstorm)

Find: `\@ViewChild\('(.*)'\)`

Replace: `\@ViewChild\('$1', \{static: true\}\)`

Answer (score 1):

you should use second argument with ViewChild like this:

```
@ViewChild("eleDiv", { static: false }) someElement: ElementRef;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

> @ViewChild(ChildDirective, {static: false}) Component

Answer (score 1):

In Angular 8, ViewChild has another param

@ViewChild('nameInput', {static: false}) component

I resolved my issue like below

@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) sort: MatSort;

Answer (score -5):

That also resolved my issue.

```
@ViewChild('map', {static: false}) googleMap;
```